# For loop returns item not in the list that is being looped through (Python 3.8.6)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, recursion

In my code below, the value passed by the for loop is not in the list that is being iterated.
I am coding a simple pathfinding function in which a start and an end point are passed, and the output is the pathway to get from the start point to the end point. The dictionary called connections has a key for all the points on the map, with the value being a list of all the other points it is connected to. You can only get from one point to another via the NODEs (think Nodes are like roads and the letters are houses).

In this case, I input a start point of 'A' and an end point of F. The expected output is:

```
['A', 'NODE1', 'NODE2', 'NODE4', 'F']
```

However, the output I get is:

```
['A', 'NODE1', 'NODE2', 'NODE3', 'NODE4', 'F']
```

After some troubleshooting, I found a very strange issue. In the print statement below, the last print is as follows:

```
NODE3 ['NODE2', 'C', 'D'] NODE4
```

The print is in the format: "key, dictionary[key], item inside dictionary[key]" However, 'item' is not actually in the list that was printed!

I am not altering the key:value pair that I am iterating through, so I have no idea why I am getting this issue. I almost never use recursion in my functions, so maybe that is where the issue comes from... Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

```
connections = {'A':['NODE1'],
               'B':['NODE1'],
           'NODE1':['A', 'B', 'NODE2'],
           'NODE2':['NODE1', 'NODE3', 'NODE4'],
           'NODE3':['NODE2', 'C', 'D'],
           'NODE4':['NODE2', 'E', 'F'],
           'C':['NODE3'],
           'D':['NODE3'],
           'E':['NODE4'],
           'F':['NODE4']}


def find_path(start_nodes, end):
    nodes = []
    for start in start_nodes:
        if end in connections[start[-1]]:
            s = start
            s.append(end)
            return s
        else:
            for item in connections[start[-1]]:
                print(start[-1], connections[start[-1]], item)
                if 'NODE' in item and item not in start:
                    s = start
                    s.append(item)
                    nodes.append(s)
    find_path(nodes, end)


s = find_path([['A']], 'F')
```

Further code explanation:
find_path takes in a list of starting points, and an end point. It then checks the dictionary to see what is connected to the starting point. If the end point is connected, it returns the path. Otherwise, it checks for nodes that are connected. Once it has found all the connected nodes, the function restarts, and stores the path up to the most recent nodes, and the connected nodes are now the starting point. It goes until the end point is found.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the `s` variable? Why not just `start.append(end)`?

Comment: You're not returning the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Maybe you want `s = start.copy()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barmar found it first but I'll spell it out (I missed his meaning first time through myself). Change this statement at the end of your function:

```
find_path(nodes, end)

# print(find_path([['A']], 'F'))
# None
```

to

```
return find_path(nodes, end)

# print(find_path([['A']], 'F'))
# ['A', 'NODE1', 'NODE2', 'NODE3', 'NODE4', 'F']
```

The way you had it, the list you try to return doesn't make it past the innermost level. This way you pass it on up to the surface.

Comment: This works! The return prevents it from returning None. However, using s = start.copy() is also required to make it work properly. I didn't realize this until now, but setting s = start wasn't doing what I thought it was. When I appended to s, both s and start are modified, and modifying a list while you are iterating through it is no good! Using .copy() eliminates this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe whats happening is that by putting `s = start` , you end up modifying the variable `start` as well. and that is why the unexpected `NODE3` makes it way to the final answer

This is because when you assign a list value to a new variable, it only stores the reference number, and modifying one variable modifies the other.

e.g

```
list_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_list = list_values

new_list.append("Interesting")

print("list_values: ", list_values)
print("new_list: ", new_list)
```

Output:

```
list_values:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'Interesting']
new_list:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'Interesting']
```

This doenst make sense for small lists but when you consider that lists can hold huge amounts of values, it makes it much faster to use reference numbers

Thus, the solution is that we need to infact copy the entire list to 's' and not just the reference number.

For this:

```
import copy

s = copy.deepcopy(start) # use this instead of s = start
```

Final code:

```
connections = {'A':['NODE1'],
               'B':['NODE1'],
           'NODE1':['A', 'B', 'NODE2'],
           'NODE2':['NODE1', 'NODE3', 'NODE4'],
           'NODE3':['NODE2', 'C', 'D'],
           'NODE4':['NODE2', 'E', 'F'],
           'C':['NODE3'],
           'D':['NODE3'],
           'E':['NODE4'],
           'F':['NODE4']}

import copy

def find_path(start_nodes, end):
    global s

    nodes = []
    for start in start_nodes:
        if end in connections[start[-1]]:
            s = copy.deepcopy(start)
            s.append(end)
            return s
        else:
            for item in connections[start[-1]]:
                if 'NODE' in item and item not in start:
                    s = copy.deepcopy(start)
                    s.append(item)
                    nodes.append(s)
    find_path(nodes, end)


find_path([['A']], 'F')
print(s)
```

Output: `['A', 'NODE1', 'NODE2', 'NODE4', 'F']`

**EDIT:** Looks like I'm late with posting this answer, already answered by @Jamie Deith and @Barmar. Anyways, I've mentioned why it didn't work as expected so that should still help.